# Passport-Local not installing for Node 5.0.0

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to install the package `passport-local` for my node 5.0.0 app, but I run into the following issue and was wondering if it was due to passport being unable to support the updated version.

```
npm install --save passport-local
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "passport-local"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install passport-local as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
```

Comment: What directory are you doing this from exactly? What is `name` in `package.json` in the current working directory?

Comment: can you try this command once and then make the `install npm i npm -g -f `

Comment: @mscdex I named it the same name as the dependency. That was the reason for the issue. I never knew that you can't name your application the same name as the dependency. Thanks for the help!